# Google Map: I can't use the MapView

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

This is for some reason is invisible to xml, and the application is crashes.
What should i do to fix it?

**manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/map_holder"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <com.google.android.maps.MapView -----> do not recognize this
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:apiKey="my_key"
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the exception i get!

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:207)
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:200)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How do i fix it?

Comment: can you provide the full mapView_layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>` in your `AndroidManifest` file and also use **Google API Android SDK** for building project and also add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` for internet permission in your AndroidManifest.

Comment: How do i add this: Google API Android SDK in IntelliJ

Comment: in `ProjectExplorer` RightClick on your project select `Open Module Settings` it will open a window from there in module setting tab select `Modules` and in right side panel there is one drop down list for Module SDK select desired Android SDK version with Google API if you have downloaded  GoogleAPI earlier, or create new from new button and give your SDK path.

Comment: Is your Activity extends from `MapActivity`

Comment: Yes and it's crashes all the time

Answer (score 0):

The right class to use is:

```
com.google.android.maps.MapView
```

Comment: Did you put this line in your AndroidManifest.xml?`<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`